# Getting error like "Implicit declaration of function 'IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL' is invalid in C99"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When i am trying to restrict nill value in coredata i am getting error like

> Implicit declaration of function 'IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL' is invalid in
>   C99

Here is my code:

```
 if ([[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL] count] == 0) {
        // Create a new managed object
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"demo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
         if (IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL(self.Name))
    {
        [newDevice setValue:self.Name forKey:@"nameofentry"];
    } else 
     {
        // Handle else case .  get self.name value is null here .

     }

         if (IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL(self.WebsiteName))
    {
        [newDevice setValue:self.WebsiteName forKey:@"sitename"];
    } else 
     {
        // Handle else case .  get self.WebsiteName value is null here .

     }


          if (IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL(self.Feedlink))
    {
        [newDevice setValue:self.Feedlink forKey:@"urloffeed"];
    } else 
     {
        // Handle else case .  get self.Feedlink value is null here .

     }

        NSError *error = nil;
        // Save the object to persistent store
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }
```

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL`? You can't just make up things.

Comment: I want to restrict to enter NULL value in coredata. I have take a reference from this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339061/how-to-restrict-entry-of-null-value-in-coredata

Comment: That must be some macro that person created. It's not a standard API.

Comment: try to use `__nonnull`

Comment: @trick14 _nonnull is not accepted.

Comment: @rmaddy then how can i set it ? I didn't find any macro related to `IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL` in that answer .

Comment: You've done what you can - ask that person what that macro is.

Comment: @rmaddy ok. thank you.commented . now don't when i will get replay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the referenced question and the answers where you found the reference to `IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL`, I'm guessing that one possible solution is to define the macro as:

```
#define IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL(x) (x && x != (id)[NSNull null])
```

Add this to the top of the .m file just after the `import` statements or add it to a common .h file that you can import.

Then code such as:

```
if (IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL(self.WebsiteName)) {
```

will become:

```
if ((self.WebsiteName && self.WebsiteName != (id)[NSNull null])) {
```

which I believe is what you are looking for.

Comment: got warning like `comparision of distinct pointer type (NSstring *) and NSNull`

Comment: still getting this warning . i have updated #define as you edited.

Comment: It's working for me as shown in my answer. Copy and paste it.

Comment: You need to include the `(id)` cast in your code. I've updated this answer to include it.

Comment: @krina_patel You added the macro (`#define`) but you aren't using it.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for fixing my typo but it should have had no bearing here since the OP should be using the referenced macro and not the fully expanded result.

Answer (score 0):

it just a macros defeine as .

```
 #define IS_NOT_NIL_OR_NULL(value)           (value != nil && value != Nil && value != NULL && value != (id)[NSNull null])
```

Comment: Checking `nil`, `Nil`, and `NULL` is redundant. Those are all the same. You only need one of those plus the `[NSNull null]` check.

Comment: @rmaddy check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908936/difference-between-nil-nil-and-null-in-objective-c

Comment: Yes, that verifies what I'm saying.